# Where can I find the returnvalue when running invoke-command in a runspaces?

Tags: powershell, runspace

> I have this PSSession which returns the Date from a Remote System.
>   Start-Session is a function which collects Host,User and Password and
>   starts a PSSession. $return is the returnvalue

```
# Start Session
$Session = Start-Session

# Start Commands in Session
$return = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {

    Get-Date

    }

$return

# Close Session
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

> If I put the snippet above into a runspace, $Data is empty.

```
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$PowerShell =[Powershell]::Create()
$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace
$Runspace.Open()

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({

        # Start Session
        $Session = Start-Session

        # Start Commands in Session
        $return = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {

            Get-Date

            }

        $return

        # Close Session
        Remove-PSSession $Session                                       
})

$AsyncObject = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

$Data = $PowerShell.EndInvoke($AsyncObject)

$Data

$PowerShell.Dispose()
```

Is this construction possible ? If yes were do I have to look for the returnvalues? At the PSSession or at the runspaceobject ?

thanks in advance.

regards

Dirk

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There are lots of ways to do that, PoshRSJob, Invoke-Parallel.ps1, PS Jobs, Invoke-Command can do queries in parallel

Comment: Good advice, I forgot to clarify. I'm not allowed to install modules....
Currently my problem is that the GUI freezes if I press a button which invokes a command on a PSsession. So I tried this way putting things in a runspaces to have functional GUI while waiting for results.